# How to add a goal to release:perform phase of maven-release-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I use the swagger-maven-plugin from kongchen. Additionally I use the maven-release-plugin. The swagger.json which is generated from swagger-maven-plugin is not part of the repo. If I build the application with mvn package the swagger.json is generated and part of the jar.

If I release the app with maven-release-plugin the swagger.json is not part of the jar-file. I checked the logs and saw that maven-release-plugin has three steps - release:clean, release:prepare and perform.

release:clean - cleans the workspace

release:prepare - logs show that the swagger-maven-plugin works and generated the swagger.json

release:perform - logs show that perform is composed of three phases (verify-completed-prepare-phases, checkout-prjoect-from-scm and run-perform-goals). I think this means that the whole project is checked out again and therefore the generated file is gone (how great is that...).

How can I add another phase to release:perform?

I found the following documentation https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-manager/index.html and know that additional preparation goals can be added https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/run-goals-before-commit.html

I need to add goals to the release:perform step (for example compile or package). How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <apiSources>
                    <apiSource>
                        <basePath>/.../api</basePath>
                        <locations>
                            <location>not.public</location>
                        </locations>
                        <info>
                            <title>${project.artifactId}</title>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </info>
                        <outputFormats>json</outputFormats>
                        <swaggerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/path</swaggerDirectory>
                    </apiSource>
                </apiSources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: How is swagger-maven-plugin configuration in your build?

Comment: I added the config.

Comment: Output directory in src location will produce problems in general because that means each build will modify the source code location which is under version control... use the default usually something like `target/generated-sources`... And the checkout during the release is intended to checkout only the code which is got from the tagged state (git tag...) before... which will fail because the build will change source locations and is not checked in correctly...

Comment: And if I change the swaggerDirectory to `target/...` - can I still serve the file via http-requests? The application is a quarkus-service which uses swagger-ui. And the ui needs that swagger-file.

Comment: I also want to mention - that's not the real issue (but the location should be changed, that's true). If I change to `target/...` it's still not in the jar because the swagger-maven-plugin is not executed during `release:perform`

Comment: Which I really doubt because you bound it to the compile phase which will run in perform part ...except you have overwritten the goals for release:perform? Or have you put the configuration in pluginManagement instead of plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `goals` parameter of `release:perform`. This contains the goals that are executed in the "inner build".

Comment: Can you elaborate? How do I set `goals` for `release:perform` in the pom.xml?

Comment: You can e.g. configure the release plugin in the POM and set this in the `<configuration>` part of the plugin definition.

Comment: I only tried `preparationGoals`, looks like I was blind. Will try it now, thanks!